# iOS : assign same selector to multiple buttons, which one is the best way?

Tags: ios, action, addtarget

Usually I'm assigning single selector to multiple `UIButton`s in this way only,

```
    [buttonOne addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonThree addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Today I found another way,

```
    SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"someAction:");

    [buttonOne addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonTwo addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonThree addTarget:self action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Please note that, I'm assigning this selector in table to each rows with above buttons.

Which way is more efficient? I assuming second way because we're creating selector for once, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, they're the same. It's just like

```
NSString *myTest = @"My text";
label1.text = myText;
label2.text = myText;
```

compared to

```
label1.text = @"My text";
label2.text = @"My text";
```

You aren't **creating a selector**, you're just **referring** to it in different ways. No memory leaks or nothing. Hope you get my point.

Comment: @Hemang Consider marking the answer as "accepted" as it helps other users to look at correct places and choose the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

as per the @Libran Coder answer, I've double check my self to prove which one is best.

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"someAction:");

NSLog(@"%p",selector);

NSLog(@"%p",NSSelectorFromString(@"someAction:"));
```

both will at the same memory address.